# Am I doing something wrong when adding an ad unit on Admob

Tags: android-studio, admob

Hello I am a new developer and I have created my first app on Android Studios.

I used test ads made by `Admob` to test if my ads worked and they did. When I finally published my app with MY ad unit code for some reason it didn't work. I then checked online and found that it may take some time before they activate, so I waited and waited, until 3 days past and still it didn't work.

Here are the steps I took:

1. Follow the tutorial made by Admob to implement code for rewarded ads
2. Add network permissions
3. Linked my published app to Admob
4. Made an ad unit on Admob by clicking "ADD AD UNIT"

I was wondering whether or not I missed a step but if I did why would the test ads work but not the real ones.
I would have liked to contact `Admob` directly but they don't seem to have any customer service email. YOU ARE MY LAST HOPE PLEASE HELP. thank you

Code: MainActivity Class

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {

    public static RewardedVideoAd mAd;
    public static RewardedVideoAd mAd2;
    public static MediaPlayer click;
    public static MediaPlayer unlock;
    public static MediaPlayer thud;

    public static InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.requestWindowFeature(getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH = dm.widthPixels;
        Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT = dm.heightPixels;

        setContentView(new GamePanel(this));

        mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        mAd2 = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mAd2.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        loadAd();

        click = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.click_sound);
        unlock = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.unlock_sound);
        thud = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.thud_sound);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    }

    private void click() {
        click.start();
    }
    private void unlock() {
        unlock.start();
    }
    private void thud() {
        thud.start();
    }


    private void loadAd() {
        if (!mAd.isLoaded()) {
            mAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
        if (!mAd2.isLoaded()) {
            mAd2.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }


    }

    // Required to reward the user.
    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
        if (GamePanel.Ad1 == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats 30 Survival Points Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (GamePanel.Ad2 == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats 100 Survival Points Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    // The following listener methods are optional.
    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        if (GamePanel.Ad1 == 1) {
            GamePanel.HighCoin = GamePanel.HighCoin + 30;
            GamePanel.Ad1 = 0;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats 30 Survival Points Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (GamePanel.Ad2 == 1) {
            GamePanel.HighCoin = GamePanel.HighCoin + 100;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats 100 Survival Points Added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {


    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    }
}
```

And to load the code i used:

```java
MainActivity.mInterstitialAd.show();

if (MainActivity.mAd.isLoaded())

MainActivity.mAd.show();
```

The ad unit code shown above is the test ad code given by Admob, which does work but I'm having trouble with the codes I make on Admob myself.

Comment: please paste your code!

Comment: first remove or mask those ad units ids if they're the real ones. Someone might use it and you could be banned. What do you see in the logs? are the ads being served? It could be a fill rate issue. You can set breakpoints in the callbacks to see if the ads get served

Comment: The ones in the code are the test ads given by admob, and they work perfectly. but its when i replace them with the ones i made in admob, thats when i have the problem.

Comment: "W/Ads: The interstitial has not loaded." this is what is says.

Comment: 07-25 19:49:34.758 30136-30230/? W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
07-25 19:49:34.760 30136-30149/? W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
07-25 19:49:34.772 30136-30136/? W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 2
07-25 19:49:34.777 30136-30136/? W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 2. i also get this error when i first open up the ad

Comment: @SataryuoSan, it seems you try to show an ad when it is not completely loaded. Maybe the test ad works, because its video was already cached. Try to call `mInterstitialAd.show()` in the callback `onRewardedVideoAdLoaded()`

Comment: I tried it still does not work. i keep getting an error code which says: W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, But i figured it out.
i forgot to put in my billing info on admob.